# how to mock imported constant from different module before test run

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I want to test `do_something` in the module `A.py` which imports an API client from `clients.py`. That client module alone has some default initialization using credentials. But even with `@mock.patch('clients.fetch_credentials')`, it looks like it's not mocking the function properly because the client seems to get initialized when I import `do_something` from `A` in `test.py` which runs before the test run. Is there a workaround for this?

```
# api_client.py

class APIClient:

  def fetch_data():
    //do something
```

```
# clients.py

import APIClient from api_client

connection_str = fetch_credentials()
api_client = APIClient(connection_str)
```

```
# A.py

import api_client from client

def do_something():
  data = api_client.fetch_data()
```

```
# test.py

from unittest import mock
from A import do_something # unit test failing from this import because client is not mocked

@mock.patch('clients.fetch_credentials')
@mock.patch('A.api_client')
def test_do_something(mock_api_client, mock_fetch_credentials):
  mock_fetch_credentials.return_value = 1
  mock_api_client.fetch_data.return_value = [1,2,3]
  do_something()
  ...
```